# Numba: How to Suppress

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I keep on getting this error in my numba code:

```
Warning 101:0: Unused argument 'self'
```

My numba code is below.  How do I suppress the error message?

```
@autojit
def initialise_output_data(self, input_data, output_data, params ):

    # Unpack Params
    #omega = params['omega']
    #beta  = params['beta']
    #gamma = params['gamma']
    psi   = params['psi']    

    # Unpack Output Data
    mu    = output_data['mu']
    s2    = output_data['sigma2']        
    res   = output_data['residuals']
    res2  = output_data['residuals2']        

    # Initialise Garch Variables
    s2[0]   = input_data[ 'sample_var' ]
    res[0]  = psi[0] / ( 1.0-psi[1] )
    res2[0] = res[0]**2
    mu[0]   = psi[0] + psi[1]*res[0]
```

Comment: ... remove the unused argument?

Comment: Well, it is part of a class.

Comment: ... don't put it in a class when it doesn't need to be?

Comment: You should probably use a `@staticmethod` decorator if `self` is not used in that method...and then you'd also avoid the warning

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress all numba warnings on a specific function with `warn=False`. For example:

```
@numba.autojit(warn=False)
def f(a, b):
    return a
```

f doesn't use b but numba does not issue a warning. This works for `@numba.jit` also. Just be careful!

Answer (score -1):

As autojit [doesn't seem to exist anymore](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/release-notes.html?highlight=autojit), and numba.jit doesn't accept the argument warn, some imperfect ways to handle this may be:

1. Disable all Numba messages of level WARNING or lower

   ```
   import logging;
   logger = logging.getLogger("numba");
   logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
   ```
2. Disable all messages of level WARNING or lower altogether

   ```
   import logging;
   logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
   ```