# Numba: suppress error to when falling back to object mode

Tags: python, numba

I want to write a function that will run either as a jitted function or else as either ordinary python or object-mode numba, depending on whether `numba` is able to do type inference.  I would actually prefer ordinary python, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that short of writing my own decorator.

Why do I want to do this?  Because I have a function `f` that takes another function `g` as an argument.  So if `g` is a jitted, then I want `f` to be jitted so the whole thing can run quickly, but if `g` is ordinary python, then I want `f` to still run, albeit more slowly.

It works fine simply annotating `f` with `@jit`, except the first time that I run the function in object-mode, I get a compile warning about failed type inference.  I would like to suppress this warning.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208465/numba-how-to-suppress) says to use `@autojit(warn=False)` but there is no longer any `autojit`.  It also says that `@jit(warn=False)` would work, but that doesn't work either, I get:

```
KeyError: "<class 'numba.core.cpu.CPUTargetOptions'> does not support option: 'warn'"
```

There must be a way to accomplish this without getting a warning, but I can't seem to google it.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's an environment variable for this. You can try setting NUMBA_DEBUG_TYPEINFER=0 when you run.

Ref: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/envvars.html?highlight=warn#envvar-NUMBA_DEBUG_TYPEINFER